# list of visited interval

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'visited': ['2015-3-1', '2015-3-5','2015-3-6','2016-3-4', '2016-3-6', '2016-3-8'],'name':['John','John','John','Mary','Mary','Mary']})
df['visited']=pd.to_datetime(df['visited'])
```

```
       visited  name
0   2015-03-01  John
1   2015-03-05  John
2   2015-03-06  John
3   2016-03-04  Mary
4   2016-03-06  Mary
5   2016-03-08  Mary
```

I wish to get the list of visited interval for two people, in this example, the outcome should be

```
  avg_visited_interval  name
0                [4,1]  John
1                [2,2]  Mary
```

How should I achieve this?
(e.g., for first example there is `4 days` between rows 0 and 1 and `2 days` between rows 1 and 2, which resulted in `[4,1]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom lambda function with [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), remove first value by position, convert to integers and lists:

```
df = (df.groupby('name')['visited']
        .apply(lambda x: x.diff().iloc[1:].dt.days.astype(int).tolist())
        .reset_index(name='intervals'))
print (df)
   name intervals
0  John    [4, 1]
1  Mary    [2, 2]
```